# Como eu imprimo uma informação no mesmo lugar da informação anterior?

Tags: python-3.x

Queria saber um comando em que eu pudesse atualizar a tela e as novas informações aparecessem no mesmo lugar, igual uma barra de "loading" que quando aumenta não cria uma cópia em baixo mas atualiza na mesma posição.

Answer (score 0):

Pra fazer uma barra de carregamento, instale e use o `tqdm`.

Na janela de comando (cmd) ou emulador de terminal:

`pip install tqdm`

Código:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    # Seu código de iteração aqui.
    # O tqdm pode ser usado em qualquer iterador.
    # Aqui só damos um time.sleep pra simular carga.
    time.sleep(0.1)
```